# Evaluate $\displaystyle\int \limits_0^{\infty} x^2 \exp( - x^2/2\pi) \mathrm{dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^\infty x^2 \exp( - x^2/2\pi) dx$$

I wish to solve this integral. I can't really do substitution because the derivative is not involved but I don't see any other way so it must be some kind of substitution. Is there a trick I am missing?

Comment: Do you know the Euler gamma function?

Comment: Use integration by parts, where $u=x$

Comment: What Will said. Note that reduces it to some constant times $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/2\pi}$. Which you can then express in terms of $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/2}$; now a well-known trick suffice to evaluate that last intergral

Answer (score 1):

As Will said: Integration by parts
$$
u=x,\qquad du=dx,\qquad v=-\pi\exp(-x^2/2\pi),\qquad dv=x\exp(-x^2/2\pi)
\\
\int_0^\infty x^2 \exp(-x^2/2\pi)\;dx = 
x\pi\exp(-x^2/2\pi)\bigg\vert_{x=0}^{x=\infty} 
+ \pi\int_0^\infty \exp(-x^2/2\pi)\,dx
\\
=\pi\int_0^\infty \exp(-x^2/2\pi)\,dx
$$
and this integral is in every calculus textbook.  Answer: $\pi^2/\sqrt{2}$.